# How does block page whitelisting work?

Tags: 7, blocks

I've created a custom entity which only should to be displayed on pages provided by the user.

To handle multiple pages, I've created a textarea where the user can enter a page per line. Just like the blocks module.

My problem here is that I don't know how to make the query that loads the correct entity by page.

My guess is that it should be something like this:

`SELECT * FROM {my_entity} WHERE pages LIKE :path`

However, that leads to the problem that 'node/1/edit' also loads the entity when the user has entered 'node/1'.

I know this functionality already exists somewhere in Drupal because it is used for blocks, but I can't find it in the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related code is found in `block_block_list_alter()` function, inside `/modules/block/block.module` file.

Here's how you would perform a similar check in your code:

```
// Get the pages to check. This should be in the same format as what Drupal
// core uses - meaning one path per line and you can use placeholders.
//
// Variable below is just as an example.
$pages_to_check = 'page1' . PHP_EOL . 'page2' . PHP_EOL . 'page3/*';
// This is a good practice, because it will make sure that paths are always
// checked consistently and won't depend on the case.
$pages = drupal_strtolower($pages_to_check);
// Compare the lowercase internal and lowercase path alias (if any).
$page_match = drupal_match_path($path, $pages);
if ($path != $_GET['q']) {
  $page_match = $page_match || drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $pages);
}
// Now you can do whatever you want based on whether or not the current path
// matches the pattern. For example:
if ($page_match) {
  // You are on one of the listed pages.
}
else {
  // You are not on one of the listed pages.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aram Boyajyan answered my question correctly. This solution, however, is not usable by me. The 'block-approach' does a page check on every block, I want to load a number of entities with a given page (or pages) from the database without preloading all entities.

I have a custom entity with a multiline textfield `path`. In my save function I make sure the path always ends with a newline, also if there is only one line.

I wrote the following function to load all entities by path(s):

```
function load_entities_by_page($paths = array()) {
  // Create a where array with placeholders.
  $where = array();
  $where_tokens = array();
  foreach ($paths as $key => $path) {
    $where[] = 'path LIKE :path' . $key;
    // Every path must end with a newline.
    $where_tokens[':path' . $key] = '%' . str_replace('%', '*', $path) . "\n" . '%';
  }

  // Retrieve all entity IDs.
  $ids = db_query('SELECT id from {entity_name} WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $where), $where_tokens)->fetchAllAssoc('id');

  return $ids;
}
```